# Shapefiles for US city and Zip level

Tags: shapefile, data, united-states, zip-codes

I already have the information for US states and Counties. I have the information in the JSON files. I want the information for **ALL** US city and Zip Code information.

I can't really navigate the US consensus sites so does anyone have the information?

I found this site where I had to pay for Zip codes for different regions. Other places I have found the info for major cities i.e 10 odd cities only. I am looking for the entire US.

Answer (score 6):

If Zip Code Tabulated Areas (http://www.census.gov/geo/reference/zctas.html, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_Code_Tabulation_Area) will do, ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/ZCTA5/tl_2013_us_zcta510.zip

These are not exactly US zip codes though, but are probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:
http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8d2012a2016e484dafaac0451f9aea24

But as others have pointed out, free zip code data is not exactly accurate (and I really don't have first hand experience with pay data). Large businesses (such as universities) and large post offices will most likely be off if they have their own zip code associated with them. Borders are not exactly defined all that well (I once learned that having mail boxes on opposite sides of the street could be two different zip codes).